ESP32 Not Detected in Device Explorer VS2022 (nanoFramework) Despite Successful Flashing and Serial Logs
I'm facing an issue where my ESP32 device is not being detected by the Device Explorer in Visual Studio 2022 (using nanoFramework). The ESP32 is properly flashed, and I can see logs when I connect via SerialPort, but the device does not show up in the Device Explorer.
Here are the specifics:

I’m using COM-port (CH340) to flash the device.

The logs from the ESP32 appear as expected, indicating that the device is functioning correctly.

When I try to deploy the application from Visual Studio, I get the following error:


1>------ Deploy started: Project: NFApp1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>Could not load file or assembly 'ICSharpCode.Decompiler, Version=8.2.0.7535, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d4bfe873e7598c49' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy completed at 19:35 and took 01,050 seconds ==========
The device is not detected, and deployment fails with the error above. The strange thing is that when I use VSCode, the application deploys and works fine, and the device is recognized without any issues.

Could this be related to a plugin issue with Visual Studio 2022? I'm using VS version 17.12.1. Has anyone experienced this issue or know how to resolve it?
Added:
Logs from .NET nanoFramework Extension:
3 [PortTcpIp network watcher started @ Thread 116 [ProcessID: 21692]]
19:34:17.529 [NanoDevices: Serial device enumeration completed. Found 0 devices]
19:34:18.549 [PortSerial device watcher stopped @ Thread 115]
19:34:18.613 [PortSerial device watcher started @ Thread 117 [ProcessID: 21692]]
19:34:18.614 [NanoDevices: Serial device enumeration completed. Found 0 devices]
19:35:24.556 [NanoDevices: device departure COM237] // turn off the port

PS: I’m using my own custom board, not a development board (Devboard).
PSS (updated 27.11.2024): After update i got this mistake:
Construction of frame content failed.
Frame identifier: ST:0:0:{ccd64499-4029-4b29-9518-00e9b10c876e}
Frame caption: Device Explorer
Exception details:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsTaskBody.DoWork(IVsTask pTask, UInt32 dwCount, IVsTask[] pParentTasks, Object& pResult)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.<>c__DisplayClass89_0.<GetCallbackForMultipleParent>b__0(Task`1[] _)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.RethrowException(AggregateException e)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.InternalGetResult(Boolean ignoreUIThreadCheck)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsTaskBody.DoWork(IVsTask pTask, UInt32 dwCount, IVsTask[] pParentTasks, Object& pResult)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.<>c__DisplayClass89_0.<GetCallbackForMultipleParent>b__0(Task`1[] _)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.RethrowException(AggregateException e)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.InternalGetResult(Boolean ignoreUIThreadCheck)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsTaskBody.DoWork(IVsTask pTask, UInt32 dwCount, IVsTask[] pParentTasks, Object& pResult)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.<>c__DisplayClass89_0.<GetCallbackForMultipleParent>b__0(Task`1[] _)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.RethrowException(AggregateException e)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.InternalGetResult(Boolean ignoreUIThreadCheck)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsTaskBody.DoWork(IVsTask pTask, UInt32 dwCount, IVsTask[] pParentTasks, Object& pResult)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.<>c__DisplayClass89_0.<GetCallbackForMultipleParent>b__0(Task`1[] _)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.RethrowException(AggregateException e)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.InternalGetResult(Boolean ignoreUIThreadCheck)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.RethrowException(AggregateException e)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.InternalGetResult(Boolean ignoreUIThreadCheck)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.<>c__DisplayClass587_0.<<-ctor>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.AwaitExtensions.ExecuteContinuationSynchronouslyAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.AsyncLazy`1.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<<GetValueAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.ThreadingTools.<WithCancellationSlow>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask`1.<<JoinAsync>g__JoinSlowAsync|7_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.<<ConstructContent>g__ConstructContentFromPackageAsync|239_1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.<>c__DisplayClass239_0.<<ConstructContent>b__2>d.MoveNext()


having the same problem, I can find the device using nanoff --listdevices but don't see it in visual studio after the visual studio update to 17.12.1, also can no longer deploy to the device with the same error "Could not load file or assembly 'ICSharpCode.Decompiler"

maybe this helps as a temporary work around, install the older version of the extension
https://github.com/nanoframework/nf-Visual-Studio-extension/releases/tag/v2022.3.0.103

Update to extension version published today.

I added some mistakes in descriptions

Is this from which extension version? Latest is 2022.12.1.6.
